# Crash issue on windows server 2016 DataCenter

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have web site in ASP.NET which host in Windows server 2016 Datacenter server. From few days I am getting below issue.

```
In w3wp__mysite.com__PID__9688__Date__08_31_2017__Time_07_50_43PM__684__First chance exception 0XE0434352.dmp the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a CLR Exception on thread 58 with the following error information:

Type:   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException 

This exception originated from System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(System.Exception).
```

My website going to crash and after very long time it is started. What is the issue with in it?

Getting many errors like above and website going to crash.

Also getting Message from DebugDiag Dump :
**"Multiple requests in the process state with the same ASP.NET Session ID were detected in the dump file. At any point of time, ASP.NET executes only one request with the same session id and the remaining requests are queued behind the request which is getting executed"**

Comment: if you ask this question from a genie, he might answer it straightaway but normal people need more information than this my friend :)

Comment: Can you find the "Error StackTrace" output generated by this UI (User Interface) exception and include this with your question? That should provide more details about the code that encountered this exception error.

Comment: I am getting this message also **"Multiple requests in the process state with the same ASP.NET Session ID were detected in the dump file. At any point of time, ASP.NET executes only one request with the same session id and the remaining requests are queued behind the request which is getting executed"**

Comment: Open a support case and share the dumps with Microsoft support team via http://support.microsoft.com